# Protractor: can't add new method to return FindElement

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I want to extend FindElement and FindArrayElement libraries. Can I write something like:

```
//ef_extend.js
protractor.ElementFinder.prototype.getColumnList = function() {
  return this.all(webdriver.By.xpath('//td[@id="SSW_1_0"]/..//tr[@class="n-grid__head-row"]/th'));
};
```

And:

```
var ps_grid = element(by.id(ps_grid_id));
var all_columns = ps_grid.getColumnList();
```

Now I always have error:

```
TypeError: Invalid locator 
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Invalid locator
    at Function.webdriver.Locator.checkLocator (c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\locators.js:244:9)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebElement.findElements (c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:1899:31)
    at c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:149:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:146:27
```

If I write 'by' instead 'By' I have this message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'xpath' of undefined

Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'xpath' of undefined
    at [object Object].protractor.ElementFinder.getColumnList (C:\Git\ng_components\test\protractor\lib\ef_extend.js:21:31)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Git\ng_components\test\protractor\resource\ps-grid_spec_2.1.a.js:28:29)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (c:\Users\Lilia.Sapurina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Git\ng_components\test\protractor\resource\ps-grid_spec_2.1.a.js:11:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `ElementArrayFinder`, but instead need to extend `ElementFinder`:

```
protractor.ElementFinder.prototype.getColumnList = function() {
    return this.all(protractor.By.xpath('//td[@id="SSW_1_0"]/..//tr[@class="n-grid__head-row"]/th'));
};
```

Comment: Yes, but when I try to write it I have the error: 'TypeError: Invalid locator'

Comment: I try to make function like $$ in documentation and I don't see the differences: ElementArrayFinder.prototype.$$ = function(selector) {
  return this.all(webdriver.By.css(selector));
};

Comment: @ЛилияСапурина thanks, have you tried with protractor's `by` (though that should not make a difference) ? Can you post the complete traceback with that `TypeError`?

Comment: With by it looks better, but now I have another error.=) Updated my question.

Comment: @ЛилияСапурина thanks, how about with `protractor.By`?

Comment: Wow! I thought that I tried it:) Thank you very much!! It works!